# What type hint can I use in Python if my type is a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I want to use type hints in Python, but there are certain cases where the type of my parameters are not clear to me... do functions have a type, or are they a special case. I would like to do something like the following:

pseudocode:

```
def run_function(function_to_run: fn):
  function_to_run(data)
```

is this possible? If so, what type should I use?

edit:
I was hoping to distinguish a function from other callables such as classes... but maybe that doesn't matter and is overly cautious.

Comment: On top of the answers below you can see an [example here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html#functions).

Comment: There's already a type-level distinction between built-in and user-defined functions that you almost certainly don't care about. What use case did you have in mind that should preclude a callable object (like a class, aka instance of `type`)?

Comment: That's a question I am trying to answer myself. I think I may not care about the distinction other than that I have a preference for being more explicit about the type. I will probably just need to experiment with Callable and see if I run into problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned in the documentation: you can use [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable).

you could for example use it this way:

```
from typing import Callable

def run_function(function_to_run: Callable[[int], str]):
    function_to_run(data)
```

if `function_to_run` is a function from `int` to `str`.

Answer (score 2):

[typing.Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.Callable) should work fine. You don't actually care that it's specifically a function, it could be a class or a callable instance of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

While you almost certainly don't care about the distinction between the various callable types, you can enforce that if you wish The `types` module provides quite a few specific names for different kinds of functions (some of which you may not even be thinking of as different types). Just to name a few:

- `types.FunctionType` and `types.LambdaType` (alias for the same underlying type)
- `types.BuiltinMethodType` and `types.BuiltinFunctionType`
- `types.MethodWrapperType`
- `types.MethodDescriptorType`